# MongoDB Replica Set Connection not created on server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

I am using MongoDB 4.0. I have a Replica Set which run on my machine and different ports that is:

```
127.0.0.1:27017 (Master)
127.0.0.1:27018 (Slave)
127.0.0.1:27019 (Arbiter)
My replica name is "xdr"
```

Now on creating the connection on localhost in my nodejs code it will create the connection i.e

```
const options = {
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
  poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  autoReconnect : true
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017, localhost:27018, localhost:27019/my_db?replicaSet=xdr, options);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//Get the default connection
var db = mongoose.connection;

//Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

Everything is fine in this on my local connection but when i will host my mongodb On seperate EC2 Instance on AWS, it will not connect to my replica set.

lets assume that my mongodb AWS IP is 12.12.13.12.

So when i will create the connection it will not be able to connect. My code is

```
const options = {
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
  poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  autoReconnect : true
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://12.12.13.12:27017, 12.12.13.12:27018, 12.12.13.12:27019/my_db?replicaSet=xdr, options);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//Get the default connection
var db = mongoose.connection;

//Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

It will generate an error i.e ""

if I will connect without replicaset then it will connect only to primary i.e

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://12.12.13.12:27017/my_db, options);
```

Is there anything which I am doing wrong on my code?

Comment: Hi Abhay - what's that error you're getting? It seems to be missing from your question, I guess just a typo mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that port 27017 and 27018 are open on your EC2 ?
You don't need to specify the arbitrer.

You have to inform mongo that you use a replicaset, with the replset option.

I use the following for my replicaset :

```
var config = {
   db: "mongodb://myMasterIp:27017/myDb,mySlave1Ip:27018/myDb"
   options: {
            user:           config.db_user,// only if you use username/password for DB authentication
            pass:           config.db_pass,// only if you use username/password for DB authentication
            replset: {
                rs_name:    "MyReplicaSetName",
                ssl:        true,// only if you use ssl for your replicaset
                sslValidate:false,// only if you use ssl for your replicaset
                sslCA:      myDbCertificate,// only if you use ssl for your replicaset
                ca:         myDbCertificate,// only if you use ssl for your replicaset
                sslKey:     myDbKey,// only if you use ssl for your replicaset
                sslCert:    myDbKey // only if you use ssl for your replicaset
            },
            socketOptions : {
               keepAlive :         1,
               connectTimeoutMS :  5000
            },
            server: { // only if you use ssl for your replicaset
               ssl:        true,
               sslValidate:false,
               sslCA:      myDbCertificate,
               ca:         myDbCertificate
               sslKey:     myDbKey,
               sslCert:    myDbKey
            },
            auth: { // only if you use username/password for DB authentication
                authdb: 'myAuthenticationDatabse'
            }
        }
};

mongoose.connect(config.db, config.options);
```